# Why is my form error message never displaying?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have two pages apply.php and registration.php.

In `registration.php`, i have

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
 //validation part
 $form_error ='';
 if(!$fullname){
  $form_error.= "Enter full name<br />";
  header('Location: apply.php');
```

And in `apply.php`, I display an error message if an error happened:

```
<p><?php if(isset($form_error))echo $form_error?></p>
<form  action="registration.php" method="post">

<label for="fullname">Fullname</label>
<input type="text" name="fullname" />
```

Why I am not getting echoed error message "Enter full name" in apply.php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting it because apply.php doesn't know about $form_error - it was initialised in registration.php, but not in apply.php.

You could do the following:

```
$_SESSION['form_error'] = "Enter full name<br />";
```

Then you could access that on apply.php.

```
<p><?php if(isset($_SESSION['form_error']))echo $_SESSION['form_error']?></p>
<form  action="registration.php" method="post">

<label for="fullname">Fullname</label>
<input type="text" name="fullname" />
```

Alternatively, you could also pass the error through the header (via GET):

```
$form_error.= "Enter full name<br />";
header('Location: apply.php?form_error=' . urlencode($form_error));
```

And access it like this in apply.php:

```
<p><?php if(isset($_GET['form_error']))echo $_GET['form_error']?></p>
<form  action="registration.php" method="post">

<label for="fullname">Fullname</label>
<input type="text" name="fullname" />
```

Comment: session is an option but overkill a bit. Do not forget to unset all errors immediately after use

Comment: Putting errors in session is not the good idea as it will unnecessarily make session heavy.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel good point - you can just do unset($_SESSION['form_error'] after it displays (if it's set).

Comment: @Yogesh Depends on the circumstance, but you could just namespace the sessions (ie. $_SESSION['errors']['form_errors']...). I don't agree that it makes the session 'heavy'

Comment: ugh yeah. and don't forget to save POST data into session as well. As for the url method - honestly, it's not an option

Answer (score 1):

Do not use header nor different files.
Put everything into one and on error just show the form.
Redirect on success only.

Make it like this:

```
<?
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { 
 if(!$fullname) $form_error.= "Enter full name<br />";
 // other validations
 if (!$form_error) { 
    //writing to database
    Header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
    exit; 
  } 
}  
?>
<form>
...
```

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Shouldn't PRG also be used for form errors? It won't have any negative effect to have the user resubmit an erroneous submission, but isn't it better practice to not?

Comment: I'd add a 303 HTTP response as a second argument to the header() function to fully implement PRG (i.e header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 303);

Comment: @Fanis sorry, I don't understand

Comment: if the submission is erroneous you are displaying the form right away, and only redirecting on success. Thus, on failures, the user can refresh the page to resend the POST, getting another error.